# Register C# COM to use in ASP Classic

Tags: c#, asp-classic, com

I built an COM Object in c# to use in an ASP Classic application, when I register using /codebase it works, if I don't use it doesn`t, my questions is why I need to use this parameter? Can it cause me any problem in the future?

I have already tried using gacutil and then without the /codebase, it seems fine, but when I run in ASP it crashes.

Is there a good way to unregister? I used /u but after registering using /codebase, it works forever even if I "unregister".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `/codebase` argument, the location of the dll will not be written to registry, and loader will not be able to find the dll.

COM servers are looked up by id (class ID or indirectly by ProgID which maps to the class ID) in the registry - loader needs to find the dll which hosts the factory function for the class, and this is done by searching the [registry for given CLSID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424(v=vs.85).aspx) and retrieving the server info.

When you install the assembly in GAC, you don't need `/codebase`. However, registering in the GAC requires the assembly to be [strong-named](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwb8f617(v=vs.110).aspx) so it is less convenient, especially during development.

Comment: tks, so what is the reason of registering without /codebase? if you can`t use anywhere

Comment: I have added info on this to the answer.